# mysql version 5.5.27 report [Err] 1005 - Can't create table 'hgwechat-ms.customer_news' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I have 3 existed tables:"customer" "news" "hallplace",here is the code how I create them:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `news`;
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hall_place`;
CREATE TABLE `hall_place` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

now i need to create a new table "customer_news":

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_news` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  ..
  `fk_customer_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_news_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_hallplace_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK8037FE9466E72C39` (`fk_customer_id`),
  KEY `FK8037FE94B522885D` (`fk_news_id`),
  KEY `FK8037FE94255BE4D0` (`fk_hallplace_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8037FE94255BE4D0` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_hallplace_id`) REFERENCES `hall_place` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8037FE9466E72C39` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8037FE94B522885D` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_news_id`) REFERENCES `news` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

it's work well on mysql version5.6,but on mysql 5.5,error shows:

> [Err] 1005 - Can't create table 'hgwechat-ms.customer_news' (errno: 150)

^_^ this is my first time using stackworkflow,i dont konw how to format.

Comment: what are the `FK8037FE9466E72C39` names? Could you try without this part?

Comment: wow I've never seen hex key names before

Comment: They could be autogenerated, by ORM for example.

Comment: Make sure there are no duplicates in those key and constraint names.

Comment: thks,all of you,although my problem is not yet solved.@TomaszKowalczyk is right,they are autogenerated by hibernate.what confused me most is  on mysql 5.6 ervery thing looks fine,but on mysql 5.5 error shows.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the format thing ^_^. now my problem solved.it was because the dismatch of "COLLATE utf8_general_ci" and "COLLATE utf8_bin".